# Sql Query with Brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a query to lists down all stored procedures which contains an insert statement for a table.

Query doesn't give result if '[' is used in like statement.

```
SELECT Name,OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) 
FROM   sys.procedures WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%[dbo].[TABLE]%'
```

Problem is with '[', but not able to get it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name,OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) 
FROM   sys.procedures WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%[[]dbo].[[]TABLE]%'
```

which escapes each instance of '[' by replacing it with '[[]'.

Comment: Yeah, Tht's work fine. I was trying different combinations but could not find the exact match. Thanks for it